# It's getting longer to get the last value of my table

Tags: postgresql, datetime, indexing

I have a table, in my Postgres database, that stores values every 10 minutes. I now have a lot of records in that table (I do not want to delete the old ones). Basically, the row contains a value and a timestamp. My SQL request is not optimized as it seems to loop through the whole table...

```
SELECT value, date FROM measures order by date desc limit 1
```

I also tried to add a filter on the date, for instance like:

```
SELECT value, date FROM measures WHERE date > date '2011-10-20' order by date desc limit 1
```

(with of course the date being dynamical). But same thing...

Is an index needed or can the query be optimized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't name your timestamp column **`date`**. A ['date' is not a 'timestamp'](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html). Also, while it's allowed in PostgreSQL, it's a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in any SQL standard. (I'll stick to `date` for the purpose of this answer, though)

That aside, there is **no need** for an [index on an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) and a `WHERE` clause like Tommy proposes. (`date(created_at)`). A **plain B-tree index** and a query with no `WHERE` clause does the job simpler and faster.

```
CREATE INDEX measures_date_idx ON measures(date);
```

Then your query will work as it is, lightening fast. B-tree indexes can be used for ascending and descending sort order equally effective. Read the chapter on **[Indexes and ORDER BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-ordering.html)** in the manual - covers most of what you need to know for your case.

---

If your table is real huge and you are concerned about index size, you **can** use a **[partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html)** for drastically reduced size. Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX measures_date_idx ON measures(date)
WHERE date > '2011-10-20 00:00:00'::timestamp;
```

Then your query will have to include the exact same `WHERE` clause as is used for the partial index. Like this:

```
SELECT value, date
FROM   measures
WHERE  date > '2011-10-20 00:00:00'::timestamp
ORDER  BY date DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off - +1 for dynamical.  You're right, your query is getting slower as without indexes, you are doing a full table scan each time you query a value.  I am not a strong postgres DB user, but it does look like you can place an index on your date field (since that is what you are mostly querying by).

[From this article:](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#expression_indexes)

> Another common example is for finding rows for a given date, where
>   we’ve stored timestamps in a datetime field but want to find them by a
>   date casted value. An index like

```
CREATE INDEX articles_day ON articles ( date(created_at) )
```

> can be used by a query containing

```
WHERE date(articles.created_at) = date('2011-03-07').
```

You may find some other information in that article interesting as well depending on your specific scenario.

Comment: thanks @tommy. In the code, you meant created_at instead of published_at, ins't ?

Comment: sorry - it was copy pasta from the article I linked to :)